# {{ entry.postDate|date }} Variable "entry" does not exist

Tags: postdate

Might be basic, but not sure where I'm doing wrong. I was trying to display the post date of an article using this code

```
{{ entry.postDate|date('medium') }}.
```

But getting the error stating "Variable "entry" does not exist."

Answer (score 2):

The `entry` variable is automatically created for the individual entry pages that you define in your section settings.

For example, if your Section has the following Site Settings:

- URI Format: `blog/{slug}`
- Template: `blog/_entry`

You can expect an `entry` variable to exist when the `blog/_entry` is loaded.

### blog/_entry.twig

```
{{ entry.postDate|date('medium') }}
```

### some-other-template.twig

If you are trying to access an entry in some other template, you would need to make sure you define the entry variable on the page.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(123).one() %}
{{ entry.postDate|date('medium') }}
```

You don't need to query the entry by ID, it was just an easy example. You can use any element query options and read more about them in the [Querying Entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#querying-entries) section of the docs.

### is defined

If you have a scenario where you don't know if the entry will exist or not, you can check for its existence using `is defined`:

```
{% if entry is defined %}
  {{ entry.postDate|date('medium') }}
{% endif %}
```

### debugging

If you are curious what does exist, you can turn on the `devMode` setting in your `config/general.php` settings and dump the variable to see more about what the application is seeing:

```
{{ dump(entry) }}
```